# Paralleled voltage sources error in LTspice

Tags: ltspice

I have the following LTspice simulation schematic. 
[image]
(It's a simplified version, just to demonstrate my dificulty). The LTspice simulator returns a paralleled voltage sources error even when the sources V5 and V6 are clearly not in parallel. Is there any walkaround that avoids putting internal series resistances with the sources? Why is this error coming up at all? I'm using the most recent version of LTspice.

Comment: What Winny said. || Advice from years of hard experience - When you find yourself saying things like "obviously not"  or  "obviously so" when you are discussing things that are NOT working as you expect, examine the basis of the "obviously" clain very very very closely. When reality does not match your expectations then, usually, reality is right. | In the case of a program (as in this case) you have a somewhat better chance of being right, but, with a program with the quality and reputation of LTSPICE, odds are it's correct.

Comment: *even when the sources V5 and V6 are clearly not in parallel.* To me it is clear that they **are** in parallel due to the "GGL" label on both. We call that a "connect by name". No visible wire, still connected.

Comment: Sorry, lesson learnt.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Look at your node naming. That “GGL” on both will short them or draw an invisible line between them. It’s intended to make your schematic less crowded and human readable, but if you take a look in your netlist which any SPICE uses behind the scenes, they are shorted.

Solution: remove the “GGL” statement for one of the nodes or just rename it.

[image]